# Are there ways to modify Rstudio's Console behavior when adding missing quotes

Tags: rstudio, quoting

I've search both SO and Rstudio's community pages and failed to find aquestion, much less and answer to this annoyance I have experienced with Rstudio. (The Rstudio help pages won't let me post a second question within 12 hours of my first, which was explained as a bug.)

If I type:

```
(test)
```

... and then realize that `test` should be quoted, then putting the cursor at the end to `test` and entering a double-quote will give me two double-quotes "".  It will not do this if I first enter a quote between `(` and `t` and then it will also not give me doubling of the double-quote character at the end of `test. Why should it matter whether I first correct my error at the end of the symbol or at the beginning? Is there anything I can do to modify this quirk> It seems that a syntax aware console editor out to be able to tell when a doubling of quotes does not make sense. It's obviously making that "decision" when the quotes are entered between an open-paren and a character. Why not suppress the unhelpful behavior when it is between a character and a close-paren?